# uib-timepicker broken when $compile

Tags: angularjs, popover

I want to use a 'uib-timepicker' inside a popover, so as I read, I need to $compile the html to bind it to angular scope:

```
app.directive('bsPopover', function($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find('#formula-nro').popover({
            html : true,
            title : '<span>Title</span>',
            content : function() {
                return $compile($('#formula_form_nro').html())(scope);
                // return $('#formula_form_nro').html();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

If I compile the code, the component brokes, but when I don't, it's shows and behaves correctly, but it is not binded to angular scope.

This is the HTML code of the component:

```
<div id="formula_form_nro" class="padding-block hide">
   .....
   <uib-timepicker ng-model="time" minute-step="15" readonly-input="true"> </uib-timepicker>
   .....
</div>
```

The following is the popover button:

```
<button id="formula-nro" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top">f(x)</button>
```

The button is inside a ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" bs-popover>
```

It looks like a bug, but I don't know if am I doing well. Maybe there is a workaround for this ..

thanks,

Comment: The first HTML belongs to what component specifically? The button has an id but it's inside a ng-repeat, that will give you troubles since ID attribute must be unique. Please, try to past all the HTML from the first element to its latest child so we can get a better global idea.

Comment: The first HTML is out of angular controller. You are right about the id inside the ng-repeat, I'm testing with just one value inside the ng-repeat.